# I want to generate a number of matrices and fill it with random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, random, numbers

hi guys i want to generate a number of matrices of 5x5 with random numbers    but this code i made only prints the same matrix over and over, whats the issue? (i am learning c++), this code just print the same matrix over and over instead of being different numbers in each matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


bool verif(int carton[5][5], int f, int c, int nume){

    for(f=0;f<5;f++){
        for(c=0;c<5;c++){
            if(nume==carton[f][c]){
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int i,cant,nume;

int main()
{
ingresa: 
    int j,cant;
    cout<< "type the number of bingo cards you want: ";
    cin>>cant;
    if(cant>100){ 
    cout<<"ERROR the max number of bingo cards is 100:"<<endl;
    goto ingresa;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=cant;i++){ 
        cout<<endl;
        cout<< "BINGO #"<<i<<endl;

    int carton[5][5]; 
    int f,c,nume; 
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(f=0;f<5;f++){
        for(c=0;c<5;c++){
            nume=1+rand()%25;
            carton[f][c]=nume;
            while(verif(carton,5,5,nume)==false){
                nume=1+rand()%25;
            }
        carton[f][c]=nume;
        }
    }
    for(f=0;f<5;f++){
        for(c=0;c<5;c++){
        cout<<setw(3)<<carton[f][c]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }

}
}
```

Comment: The [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library and the [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) algorithm seem, at first glance, like obvious places to start reading.

Comment: `bool verif(int carton[5][5],` - Don't try to pass C-style arrays like that. Use a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL))` that's a really bad (second resolution) seed of a rather bad random number generator. Don't use `srand` / `rand` in new code.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I only see one Matrix created in your Programm.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you call `srand()` multiple times, resetting the state of the random number generator to the same value (unless you are lucky and the clock steps a second between iterations). You should only seed the pseudo random number generator *once*.

Minor details:

- Your algorithm for filling the array is expensive. Instead of generating a random number and testing if that number is already taken, generate the numbers in order (1-25) with [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and then [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the array.
- Don't use `srand()` & `rand()`. There are much better random generators in the standard library, like [`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)
- Don't use `goto`. Make a `while(true)` loop and `break` out of it when the user has entered a valid number.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}()); // A seeded PRNG
    
    int carton[5][5];

    // fill the array with 1-25
    std::iota(&carton[0][0], &carton[0][0] + 25, 1);

    // make the order properly random
    std::shuffle(&carton[0][0], &carton[0][0] + 25, prng);

    // You can use the prng to generate a random number in the range [1,25]
    // with the help from uniform_int_distribution:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 25);
    std::cout << "A random number 1-25: " << dist(prng) << '\n';

}
```